# How to save the lat, lon coordinates of current location before fetching the API in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

**Hello Guys,**

I have some stuck of the **Geolocation** , I'm accessing my current location to use the latitude and longitude on my Link API but I have some issue that does not access the API and the result is cannot find the JSON data originally, when I test of them I saved into separated variable but doesn't work correctly, Now how to save them before fetch the API ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhwNM.png)

my Code here :

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TextInput,
      ScrollView,
      Image,
      ActivityIndicator
    } from "react-native";
    import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome";


    export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          dataSource: [],
          latitude: null,
          longitude: null,
          error: null
        };
      }
      async componentDidMount() {
        this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
          position => {
            this.setState({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              error: null
            });
          },
          error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 1000,
            distanceFilter: 5
          }
        );
    var myLat = `${this.state.latitude}`;
        var myLon = `${this.state.longitude}`;
     let API_WEATHER = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${myLat}&lon=${myLon}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`;

fetch(API_WEATHER)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        console.log(responseJson.weather);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
 var icon =
      this.state.dataSource.main.temp <= 20
        ? require("./assets/cloudySun.png")
        : require("./assets/sunny.png");
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.head}>
          <Text style={styles.titleApp}>Weather App</Text>
          <View
            style={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
            <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
            {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.defaultWeather}>
          <View style={styles.infoDegree}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 80, color: "#42434B", paddingBottom: 0 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.main.temp}°
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, padding: 7 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.name},{this.state.dataSource.sys.country}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#42434B", fontSize: 20, padding: 2 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.weather[0].description}
            </Text>
          </View>
 var icon =
      this.state.dataSource.main.temp <= 20
        ? require("./assets/cloudySun.png")
        : require("./assets/sunny.png");
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.head}>
          <Text style={styles.titleApp}>Weather App</Text>
          <View
            style={{
              flexGrow: 1,
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
          >
            <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
            <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
            {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.defaultWeather}>
          <View style={styles.infoDegree}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 80, color: "#42434B", paddingBottom: 0 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.main.temp}°
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, padding: 7 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.name},{this.state.dataSource.sys.country}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#42434B", fontSize: 20, padding: 2 }}>
              {this.state.dataSource.weather[0].description}
            </Text>
          </View>
         </View>
</ScrollView>



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#F2F4FA"
  },
  head: {
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  titleApp: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "400",
    color: "#000"
  },
  defaultWeather: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
  },
  infoDegree: {
    padding: 15,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  searchSection: {
    marginBottom: 50,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    shadowColor: "#eee",
    shadowOffset: { width: 10, height: 3 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 5
  },
  searchIcon: {
    padding: 10
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    color: "#424242"
  },
  statusWeather: {
    width: 210,
    padding: 20,
    margin: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#e8ebf7"
  },
  ImgWeek: {
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 23
  },
  TextStatus: {
    color: "#607498",
    fontSize: 17,
    padding: 10
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following, pass the callback to setState, there you will get the new lat, long :

```
  componentDidMount() {
            this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
              position => {
                this.setState({
                  latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                  longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                  error: null
                },()=>{
        var myLat = `${this.state.latitude}`;
            var myLon = `${this.state.longitude}`;
         let API_WEATHER = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${myLat}&lon=${myLon}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`;

    fetch(API_WEATHER)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            console.log(responseJson);
            console.log(responseJson.weather);
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false,
              dataSource: responseJson
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });

});
              },
              error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
              {
                enableHighAccuracy: true,
                timeout: 20000,
                maximumAge: 1000,
                distanceFilter: 5
              }
            );

      }
```

Comment: I'm trying but it takes a many time without result, I will be trying them in the real device right now, but can you explain to me why are you passing in the callback? and what's different without callback setState ?

Comment: setState is an async method, it takes time before actually asigning the result to state, the callback you pass to the setState gets called once the asigning operation is complete, if you are trying to access the state values in next statement after setState there is a possibility that you will get previous values rather than new values. In your case, watch position itself is async and you don't know when you will receive the result, thats why you are using the callback and once we get lat long values we are doing the fetch operation inside that callback(this is may be root cause of ur problem)

Comment: yeah, that's the right man, your code I run but in my emulator, it takes much time I know because it's not the right location but when I run the App on my real mobile it's work fine but the Spinner doesn't work! On the contrary in ُemuolatore, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some performance on your code. I hope this helps.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator
} from "react-native";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome";


export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ApiKeyRef = 'hdjdjdjjd555555555555'

    this.watchPositionOpts = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 1000,
      distanceFilter: 5
    }
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: [],
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      this.watchPositionSuccess, this.watchPositionFail, this.watchPositionOpts 
    );              
  }     

  componentWillUnmount(){
    //dont forget to clear
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
    navigator.geolocation.stopObserving();
  }           

  watchPositionSuccess = (position) => {
    this.setState({ 
      latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
      longitude: position.coords.longitude, 
      error: null
    }, () => this.fetchCallback());
  }

  watchPositionFail = (err) => {
    this.setState({ error: err.message })
  }

  fetchCallback = () => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state
    const req = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=metric&appid=${this.ApiKeyRef}`;
    const callback = (responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson)
      console.log(responseJson.weather)
    }

    fetch(req)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: responseJson}, ()=> callback(responseJson)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))      
  }

  render() {

      const { 
        isLoading, 
        dataSource, 
        error, 
        latitude, 
        longitude 
      } = this.state; 

      if (isLoading) {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
          </View>
        );
      }

      const icon = dataSource.main.temp <= 20 ? require("./assets/cloudySun.png") : require("./assets/sunny.png")

      return (
          <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.head}>
              <Text style={styles.titleApp}>Weather App</Text>
              <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Text>Latitude: {latitude}</Text>
                <Text>Longitude: {longitude}</Text>
                {error && <Text>Error: {error}</Text>}
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.defaultWeather}>
              <View style={styles.infoDegree}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 80, color: "#42434B", paddingBottom: 0 }}>
                  {dataSource.main.temp}°
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, padding: 7 }}>
                  {dataSource.name},{dataSource.sys.country}
                </Text>
                <Text style={{ color: "#42434B", fontSize: 20, padding: 2 }}>
                  {dataSource.weather[0].description}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank u man, but I don't know the app doesn't work just white screen i show without  ActivityIndicator !!! i think it takes times?

Comment: @AnasTe could you upload an img ?

Comment: @AnasTe could you also post the styles?

Comment: yup it takes much time to open but I have an issue in the if statement can you check the line contain **const icon**

Comment: when i remove the line of Icon it's work fine !  the error is invalid to call this line **const Icon**

Comment: Try again. just copy that line after if statement

Comment: nope, not work :/ can you check? https://imgur.com/a/Nw0ytof   and Indicator doesn't work :((

Comment: OH it's **require**, I took your time but why ActivityIndicator doesn't work the code is right where the wrong !!!

Comment: @AnasTe did you follow the instructions here ?? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation